# Fetching all the tables and their data in MSSQL and mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, t-sql

Can you guys tell me how to fetch all the tables along with their records considering we don't know the table names in the database.

Such as :

```
use my_database
select * from information_schema.tables 
-- gives all the tables from a database
```

Also it would be great if you can give mySQL and MSSQL queries.

I thought it would work but didn't work out:

```
select * from (select [TABLE_NAME] from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES)
```

Comment: I don't think you can do this using pure queries, and definitely not with one query - especially in some database-indepenendent manner.  You'll need to establish the DB connection, then read the connection metadata to get a list of tables, then finally loop over this list retrieving data for each of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For SQL Server you can use this:

```
exec sp_msforeachtable 'select * from ?'
```